# Who can explain this Haskell function?

Tags: haskell

The Haskell function

```
foo = zipWith ($) . repeat
```

does exactly the same as

```
map
```

but I cannot see why :-(
Who can give an explanation?
Thx a lot!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

OK, so we have

```
foo = zipWith ($) . repeat
```

which is the same as

```
foo f = zipWith ($) (repeat f)
```

The `repeat f` generates an infinite list of copies of `f`. Then `zipWith` uses the `($)` operator to apply each element of the [infinite copies of `f`] list to each element of the incoming list. Which is what `map` does.

Yes?